# Can't find or install package "libiberty"

Tags: 13.10, software-installation

I'm running a ./configure script to install a program on a newly installed 13.10 ubuntu.

I'm told that libiberty should come with binutils or gcc, but it is not being found.

There is no information on  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libiberty/ that  I am able to make use of.

I don't know how to install packages without using apt. I can add a repo to the sources though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If configure is just looking for the `libiberty` development files and static library then install `binutils-dev` and `gcc-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-dev gcc-dev
```

**Note**: to install the libiberty headers on a 13.10 system, the only way is to download the deb file (amd64 or i386) and call `dpkg -i`.

First choose the right package to install:
`libiberty-dev_20131116-1_amd64.deb` or `libiberty-dev_20131116-1_i386.deb`

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libiberty-dev/download
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libiberty-dev/download

Select a mirror to download the .deb file

In a terminal go to the folder where you saved the deb file and type (for amd64):

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libiberty-dev_20131116-1_amd64.deb
```

Thanks to steeldriver for his comment about `binutils-dev`

Comment: `libiberty-dev` package is only available for Ubuntu 14.04. see http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libiberty-dev

Comment: Doesn't work under ubuntu, that package is not in the apt repo :/

Comment: I've updated my answer for 13.10

Comment: Actually on 13.10, at least the headers plus a static library appear to be available via the `binutils-dev` package.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got word back from another student in my university that it was

binutils-dev

and

gcc-dev that needed installed

Shame I can't tag this question with the "libiberty" tag so that other noobs can find it.

Comment: @user3507595: I've updated my answer accordingly and added the tag to your question

Answer (score 3):

On 13.10, the header file and at least a static library appear to be available via the `binutils-dev` package.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"
$ 
$ dpkg -S libiberty
binutils-dev: /usr/lib/libiberty_pic.a
binutils-dev: /usr/include/libiberty.h
binutils-dev: /usr/lib/libiberty.a
$
```

You can install it via a GUI package manager such as the Software Center or via the command line using

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that libiberty is not in the repos already built in. You can try searching on the internet for a repo and try installing it. Use a ubuntu repo if you want to be safe. I found this: (not a repo, but it is the package for kubuntu(a part of ubuntu with KDE)) http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/kubuntu-ppa_backports/saucy/main/base/libiberty
. Be careful though, it might not be safe. I'd rather recommend using your favorite repo.

AnonymousJP